# Highlight entire row of a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I want to highlight the entire row of a my QTableWidget when I click on one cell of this row.

I already put a connection between an activation of my cell and my function highlightRow :

```
QObject::connect(ui->variableTableWidget,SIGNAL(cellActivated(int,int)), this, SLOT(highlightRow()));
```

Now I have to write my function, but I don't know how could I know which cell is activated.
Is there a function in the QTableWidget that is suppose to return all activated cell ?

Comment: What does "line" mean? A **row** or a **column**??

Comment: Sry i'm french, it means a row, I will edit now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call this on your table widget when it is created

```
setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

this will make it so that when you click on a cell that row is selected